# Проблема с Windows Forms C++/CLI. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli

Создал проект Windows Forms согласно этой [инструкции](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6fbde42-d872-4ab3-8000-41ab22a4a584/visual-studio-2017-windows-forms?forum=winformsdesigner) но в результате получаю ошибку (см. скриншот). Кто уже сталкивался с такой проблемой?

[image: скриншот ошибки]

И вот код, который написан в MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Calculator::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что `Main` надо писать с маленькой буквы :)

Comment: [В документации пишут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/managed-types-cpp-cli?view=vs-2017#main_functions) что аргументы функции main не могут быть управляемыми типами.

Comment: А что за `^` ??? Это новый стандарт C++ ??

Comment: @vegorov Не знаю, серьезно вы спрашиваете или нет, но это С++/CLI, расширение С++ от Microsoft для программирования под .NET (не только не новое, но и уже довольное устаревшее). На вопрос уже поставили соответствующую метку.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо. Буду знать теперь.

Answer (score 3):

Main должно быть с маленькой буквы, спасибо Harry

Comment: @VladSpirin это исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, а не правка и не дополнение

Comment: @VladSpirin почему? написание Main с маленькой буквы отлично решает проблему из вопроса. Если провести это правкой - то сам по себе вопрос потеряет смысл, а он не такой уж очевидный, если пытаешься на C++-cli с C# перейти :)

Comment: @PashaPash Согласен, надеюсь не закроют, комментарий удаляю. Но остался осадок, что ответ надо расписать чуть-чуть